# Calculate the Probability for a 4-digits PIN

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to ask for Help in the following problem:

What is the Probability for a four-digits PIN not to have repeated digits?
I tried to solve it using combinations. 
Is that solution correct? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Combinations? Doesn't the order of the numbers in the PIN matter? Anyway, please explain further, because "combinations" is not good enough to explain your strategy. Give an answer, for example if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If you want to make sure you don't repeat digits, think about HOW you have to choose them and what your options are for each placeholder.

What could the first digit be? How will that affect the digits that follow?